# How do I decide the font size in figures for ACM SIG?

Tags: fontsize, acm

I am using the [ACM SIG Template](http://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) for a conference paper. And I'd like to insert several figures plotted by matplotlib and MS visio. **What is the recommended font size in figures** (for xlable, ylable, legend, etc.)?

I got lost as there are a lot of options in the class file `sig-alternate-05-2015.cls`.

```
$ grep 'fontsize' sig-alternate-05-2015.cls 
    \@setfontsize\normalsize\@ixpt{10.5\p@}%\ninept%
    \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{11.5\p@}%\ninept%
  \newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt{8\p@}}
  \newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt{6\p@}}
  \newcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiipt{14\p@}}
  \newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xivpt{18\p@}}
  \newcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xviipt{20\p@}}
  \newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xxpt{25\p@}}
  \newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@xxvpt{30\p@}}
  \newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viiipt{9\p@}}
  \newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vipt{7\p@}}
  \newcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large\@xiiipt{15\p@}}
  \newcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large\@xvpt{20\p@}}
  \newcommand\LARGE{\@setfontsize\LARGE\@xixpt{22\p@}}
  \newcommand\huge{\@setfontsize\huge\@xixpt{30\p@}}
  \newcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge30pt{36\p@}}
\toappear{\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\toappear{\fontsize{7.5pt}{8.5pt}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
```

---

If the font size in figures should be the same as the body text, the answer is 10.5 or 11.5?

```
\newcount\ACM@basesize
\ACM@basesize=9\relax

\ifnum\ACM@basesize=9\relax
  \renewcommand{\@ptsize}{}
  \renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
    \@setfontsize\normalsize\@ixpt{10.5\p@}%\ninept%

\fi
\ifnum\ACM@basesize=10\relax
  \renewcommand{\@ptsize}{}
  \renewcommand{\normalsize}{%
    \@setfontsize\normalsize\@xpt{11.5\p@}%\ninept%

\fi
```

Comment: Doesn't ACM decide about the layout of submissions?

Comment: I didn't find the descriptions about figures.

Comment: I bet the class authors made it to fit the requirements, but you can never be sure with templates.

Comment: if i had to guess, it would be that you should use the same size as the body text.  it shouldn't be larger.  most important is that you make the figures at the "final" size at which they should be printed, so that they don't have to be reduced to fit.